# xsd dataset not showing for rdlc report ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, report

I have created a report file in my ASP application, `Statistics.rdlc`
I have created a Data Source which connects to my local database.
I now wish to add a Dataset using a specific query I have written, however when I right click Datasets in the Report Data panel and select my Data source I am presented with a list of the tables on the database under 'Available datasets'.

What I am expecting to see here is the Dataset1.xsd I created which contains the following:

[image]

That Query contains the SQL I wish to apply to my report table, can any point out what im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to create a table adapter not a query.

This post helped me out:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a72401/rdlc-report-generation-using-dataset/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes report view doens't allow when you use "SELECT * FROM". Put all columns instead of *. 
Ex: SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table